# How to convert Json into associative array or key value array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following Json which i need to insert into a table.
I want to convert each student detail into a row.
Because if i loop through the rows as per the existing structure i am reading one column as a row.

```
var json   {  
       "Students":[  
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Allan"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"123"
             }
          },
          {  
             "name":{  
                "value":"Frank"
             },
             "number":{  
                "value":"456"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

Ideally i want to the above as

```
{ "name": "Allan", "number": 123}; 
{ "name": "Frank", "number": 456};
```

I am looping through the Json as below

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(json);
for (var key in objectKeys)
{       

        var student = json.Students;

        for (var i = 0; i < student .length; i++) {

            for (var column in json.Students[i]) {
                window.print(column);
                window.print(json.Students[i][column].value);

            }

        }
    }
```

NOTE: No JQuery, want to achieve the above through normal Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the data, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var json = {"Students":[{"name":{"value":"Allan"},"number":{"value":"123"}},{"name":{"value":"Frank"},"number":{"value":"456"}}]};

let result = json.Students.map(o => ({
  name: o.name.value,
  number: o.number.value
}));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to access the data, you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

```js
var json = {"Students":[{"name":{"value":"Allan"},"number":{"value":"123"}},{"name":{"value":"Frank"},"number":{"value":"456"}}]};

json.Students.forEach(o => console.log({name: o.name.value, number: o.number.value}));
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Our compiler doesn't support Jquery, can it be done in simple javascript

Comment: @HakanSukar - It is simple Javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {  
   "Students":[  
      {  
         "name":{  
            "value":"Allan"
         },
         "number":{  
            "value":"123"
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":{  
            "value":"Frank"
         },
         "number":{  
            "value":"456"
         }
      }
   ]
}

var studentData = JSON.stringify(json.Students);
var convertedData = JSON.parse(studentData.replace(/\{\"value\"\:/g,"").replace(/\}\,\"number/g,',"number').replace(/\"\}\}/g,'"}'));
```

Try this :)

Comment: Hi Nishikant, Thanks for your answer how to i loop through that array and read each name and number.    for (var i = 0; i < convertedData.length; i++) {
    alert(convertedData[i]);
    
}

Comment: yes, once you get converted data in an array of objects, use any valid loop to iterate through an array like for, forEach or map.  Each value in the array is an object so you can read its properties

Answer (score -1):

**No map or reduce. Just classic Javascript.**

```js
var json = {
  "Students": [{
      "name": {
        "value": "Allan"
      },
      "number": {
        "value": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "value": "Frank"
      },
      "number": {
        "value": "456"
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (var student of json["Students"]) {
  console.log(student); //your logic goes here.
}
```